# Learnyounode, functions with callbacks - Juggling Async

Tags: javascript, node.js

im very very new to Node.js, javascript in general, and also functional programming (which node is if im not mistaken?)

Im currently on stage of doing learnyounode tutorials.
I know i can find all the solutions and work it out just fine, but im a little curious why wouldnt my code work...

If anyone is familiar with the learnyounode im stuck at "Juggling async".

The code that i wrote:

```
var http = require("http");

var addriee = [process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]];

function getStuffFromNet(address, callback) {
  http.get(address, function getShitDone(response) {
    var dataToCallback = "";
    response.on("error", function(data) {
      callback(data, null);
    });

    response.on("data", function(data) {
      dataToCallback+=data;
    });

    response.on("end", function(data) {
      callback(null, dataToCallback);
    });

  });
};

function printToConsole(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

printToConsole(getStuffFromNet(addriee[0]));
```

My goal was to reuse function that would get "stuff from net", the error i get is:

```
learnyounode run http-get3.js 
undefined

/home/ubuntu/workspace/learnyounode/http-get3.js:17
      callback(null, dataToCallback);
      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/learnyounode/http-get3.js:17:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Comment: `callback` is undefined, you didn't pass any function. Did you mean `getStuffFromNet(addriee[0], printToConsole)`?

Comment: Of course, you are right... This stuff is very confusing for a begginer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the last callback null and not data ?
Also it might be handier to not initialize

> var dataToCallback = "";

to

> var dataToCallback;

because else you can't use data

> typeof dataToCallback !== 'undefined'

Not sure about 's atm.

Also try to comment you're code a lot more. Especially when you're learning it.

Example of some debugging level I have (noob or not I quickly find errors this way)

> ```
>         /**
>          * Divest the desired amount
>          */
>         socket.on("divest", function (amount) {
>             error.debug(classname + "Divest is called [" + amount + "]");
> ```

```
            invest.divest(hash, amount, function (err, callback) {
                if (!err) {
                    error.debug(uid, name + "  />divesting [CBACK]" + callback);
                } else {
                    error.debug(uid, name + "  />divesting [ERROR]" + err);
                }
                socket.emit("done", true);
            });
        });
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: I was thinking, the first argument of a call back should be an error - so if the response emits "end" event, there is no error? Also, my way of thinking was - if i initialize with value of "" it implies the variable is type of string? I was learning mostly strongly typed languages, so it kinda fell into place by heat

Answer (score 0):

To explain your situation, the data was read to the end and "`callback`" is invoked, 
but the "`callback`" was not defined at the last line of your script.

If you wonder why the `data.on("error" .....)` wasn't triggered, It will only be triggered by data error of the `http.get()`, it means you are "ABLE TO READ DATA" from the URLs, so the `http.get()` will trigger `data.on("data" ....)` and `data.on("end" .....)` only.